# spurious cannot insert NULL error in ADO.NET

Tags: ado.net

I'm getting an error when trying to insert a new row into a SQL Server table using ADO.NET, that column CITY does not accept nulls.

I am invoking the DataAdapter's `Update` method, supplying the Table associated with the current Row of the DataRowView as the argument:

```
    DA.Update(drv.Row.Table);
```

The DataAdapter's `InsertCommand` includes this parameter declaration:

```
c.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@city", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25, "city"));
```

When I examine the data objects in the debugger, the CITY value is present in position `[4]` (see below).

Is there anything else which could be causing this error?

```
?drv.Row.Table.Columns.List
Count = 20
    [0]: {id}
    [1]: {practiceid}
    [2]: {addr1}
    [3]: {addr2}
    [4]: {city}
    [5]: {state}
    [6]: {zipcode}
    [7]: {geozip}
    [8]: {wheelchair}
    [9]: {transportation}
    [10]: {braille}
    [11]: {fax}
    [12]: {phone}
    [13]: {remarks}
    [14]: {createdby}
    [15]: {datecreated}
    [16]: {lastupdatedby}
    [17]: {lastupdated}
    [18]: {rowversion}
    [19]: {dirty}

?drv.Row.ItemArray
{object[20]}
    [0]: -1
    [1]: 7819
    [2]: "123 Main St"
    [3]: {}
    [4]: "Anywhere"
    [5]: "KS"
    [6]: "35577"
    [7]: {}
    [8]: true
    [9]: true
    [10]: true
    [11]: {}
    [12]: {}
    [13]: "test remark"
    [14]: "SRVR1\\Tim"
    [15]: {}
    [16]: {}
    [17]: {}
    [18]: {}
    [19]: false
```

Comment: could you show your insert statement?

Comment: I removed the "not null" constraint from the  `city` column in the SQL Server database, and tried the insert again, using the same "bad" record, and it was inserted successfully, and the record in the database did indeed have a city value.  So it is definitely a spurious error.  I can't figure out what is causing ADO.NET to think there's no value being provided for city.